# Getting the value of the selected option tag in a select box

Tags: jquery

I have an select box

```
<select name="type1">
   <option value="1">Laser Printer</option>
   <option value="2">Line Printer</option>
</select>
```

Now I have a button with id `#New1` when this button gets clicked I need to display  the value between the option tag that was selected. Eg if Laser Printer is selected I need to get Laser Printer and not 1

My code thus far

`alert($("select[name=type1]:selected").val().text());` but this returns undefined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the text of the selected option:

```
alert($("select[name='type1'] option:selected").text());
```

Comment: Which is equivalent to `alert($('select[name=type1]').find('option:selected').text());`, if that syntax feels more familiar, like if you already have your select in a cached variable -- `alert($mySelect.find('option:selected').text());`

Comment: This answer doesn't cover multiple selects.