# Get SELECT's value and text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the value of the selected option tag in a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380604/getting-the-value-of-the-selected-option-tag-in-a-select-box)

For a SELECT box, how do I get the value and text of the selected item in jQuery?

For example,

```
<option value="value">text</option>
```

Comment: this should not be marked duplicate. the possible duplicate asked how to get value even though that questioner meant text - this post correctly asks the question how to get the text of a select - i pulled up this question and passed over the other during a search - so marking this a duplicate is not helpful even though the resulting answers were the same because the questions were not. quick to judge != helpful

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="value">text</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
var txt = $("#ddlViewBy option:selected").text();
var val = $("#ddlViewBy option:selected").val();
```

**[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cxgus/1/)**

Comment: selected value does not need the option:selected selector. $(#ddlViewBy).val() by itself is sufficient

Answer (score 12):

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text(); // selected option text
$("#yourdropdownid").val(); // selected option value
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('select').val()  // Get's the value

$('select option:selected').val() ; // Get's the value

$('select').find('option:selected').val() ; // Get's the value

$('select option:selected').text()  // Gets you the text of the selected option
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zXcHB/)

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this, to get the currently selected value:

```
$('#myDropdownID').val();
```

& to get the currently selected text:

```
$('#myDropdownID:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 4):

on the basis of your only `jQuery` tag :)

**HTML**

```
<select id="my-select">
<option value="1">This is text 1</option>
<option value="2">This is text 2</option>
<option value="3">This is text 3</option>
</select>
```

**For text** --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-select").change(function() {
        alert($('#my-select option:selected').html());
    });
});
```

**For value** --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-select").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```