# Ajax returns undefined on a Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have this which posts data to an express/node app and then writes to MongoDB
All works well except the select customer: $('#custs').val(), which is showing undefined.
This should be simple, No exceptions are throwing either on the client or server side...
How do I get the value of the select?

Thanks In Advance!

```
     function sendIt(){             
             $.ajax({                
            url: "/doIt",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",               
            data: JSON.stringify({                   
                customer: $('#custs').val(),                     
                userID: $('#userID').val(),
                resource: $('#resID').val(),
                ticket: $('#ticketID').val(),
                issueDate: $('#IssueDate').val(),
                issueTime: $('#IssueTime').val(),
                TechName: $('#TechName').val(),
                Urgent: $('#isUrgent').val(),
                description: $('#descript').val()
            }),                 
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,

                            <select id="custs">
                             <option value="JSC">JSC Co</option>
                              <option value="AGM">More</option>
                              <option value="SWW">Spunge Work</option>
                              <option value="BBV">BBV Corp</option>
                              <option value="UGL">UGL Corp</option>  
                            </select>
```

Comment: Could you provide the <select /> you're talking about?

Comment: Did you specify values and IDs? Can you provide the HTML code?

Comment: Are you sure an element with id `custs` exists and has the `value` property? Could you post the HTML?

Comment: Assuming you have an element with an `id` of `custs` which contains a value, then that is exactly how you would get that value.  There's nothing wrong with that line of code.

Comment: does we have to guess the resaon?

Comment: Here it is
<select id="custs">
                             <option value="JSC">JSC Co</option>
                              <option value="AGM">More</option>
                              <option value="SWW">Spunge Work</option>
                              <option value="BBV">BBV Corp</option>
                              <option value="UGL">UGL Corp</option>  
                            </select>

Comment: @RobD when you say it is "showing undefined" do you mean when it gets to the server, or have you looked at the JSON itself to determine that `undefined` is being sent to the server?

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be

```
function sendIt(){             
        // ...               
            customer: $('#custs option:selected').val(),                     
        // ...
        }),                 
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
```

?

[Get SELECT's value and text in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614308/jquery-get-selects-value-and-text)

Comment: Although the code you provided would in fact get the value for the `select`, `$('#custs').val()` will, too.

Comment: So the code provided will do the same as the OP's, why downvote an answer that is not wrong?

Comment: It is wrong. It's not a correct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for all the help,tried everything, its still not working coming through as undefined??? At this point the only thing I can do is drop the select and have them type it into a text box, yuk!

Comment: Is your select being ajax-loaded in your page or is it created when the DOM is loaded?

Comment: When the DOM is loaded, for now

Comment: Ok, I figured out its not on the client its in my app.post, i think its this customerID = req.body.custs, Strange, all the others work fine???