# JS specify which option value to to call

Tags: javascript

I have appended country names and iso codes from a php routine to option value of `$('#innerSelect')`

```
$('#innerSelect').append("<option value=" + country['data'][i]['code'] + ">" + country['data'][i]['name'] + "</option>");
```

However, I'm now wondering is there a way to declare when I want the code and when I want the name?

For example

```
countryName = $('#innerSelect option:selected').val(name)
countryCode = $('#innerSelect option:selected').val(code)
```

I have future API calls where some need the name as a parameter and some need the code, so it would be nice to be able to tell JS which one to use based on the  $('#innerSelect')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get SELECT's value and text in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614308/get-selects-value-and-text-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .val() to get the value, and .text() to get the name (ie what you see in the select)

```js
console.log($("#innerSelect option:selected").val(),$("#innerSelect option:selected").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="innerSelect">
 <option value="US">USA</option>
 <option value="CA">CANADA</option>
</select>
```